# data.table ifelse with multiple conditions not returning desired output

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table and an assigned column like this:

```
a <- c("CA","Canada",NA, "Canada", "CA")
b <- c("pass", NA,"pass","pass","pass")

dt <- data.table(a,b)

dt[,c := ifelse((a=="CA"|a=="Canada") & b=="pass", "pass","fail")]
```

My output looks like this:

```
    a    b    c
 CA      pass pass
 Canada  <NA> <NA>
 <NA>    pass <NA>
 Canada  pass pass
 CA      pass pass
```

As I understand, where column a is "CA" and column b is "pass" or where column a is "Canada" and column b is "pass", a "pass" should be returned for column c and when the condition fails a "fail" should be passed in column c.  However, I am getting NAs for all columns where an NA is anywhere in the column.  Is there a way around this behavior without having to coerce all NAs to ""?

Comment: `NA`s can't be compared. `1==NA` for instance always returns `NA`. If you think of `NA` as "any possible value" then the correct result could be "pass" or "fail". So instead you get `NA`

Comment: *However, I am getting NAs for all columns where an NA is anywhere in the column.* Do you mean for all **rows**?

Comment: Yes, Any rows where an NA is being passed

Comment: ```dt1[,c := ifelse((a=="CA"|a=="Canada") & b=="pass", "pass","fail")][, 
     c := ifelse(is.na(c), "fail", c)][]```

Comment: That second `[ ]` command could be shortened to `...[ is.na(c), c := "fail" ]`.

Comment: @r2evans right. That's just not about shortening the command, it's also more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you cannot use `==` on `NA` and expect meaningful results, as @thelatemail said in his comment. However, one trick is that `%in%` *does* allow easier comparison, so you can change to this:

```r
dt[,c := ifelse(a %in% c("CA", "Canada") & b %in% "pass", "pass", "fail")]
#         a    b    c
# 1:     CA pass pass
# 2: Canada <NA> fail
# 3:   <NA> pass fail
# 4: Canada pass pass
# 5:     CA pass pass
```

Comment: or `fifelse` since recent release

Comment: I hadn't seen that yet ... a **huge** "thank you" for *"In contrast to `ifelse` attributes are copied from `yes` to the output. This is useful when returning `Date`, `factor` or other classes"*.

Comment: @jangorecki, perhaps you have the clout to submit that patch back to base R? Don't know how many times attribute-loss has bitten me ...

Comment: it would break to much existing code, R is very conservative on that. Matt already proposed that. Take a look at recent NEWS.md, there are much more  nice things in recent release.

Comment: or `%chin` if speed helps.